# CSS3 Flag/wave movement with text inside

Tags: html, css

So I'm working on a project that requires me to make an animated flag purely with HTML5 and CSS3—looking something [like this](https://anaegm-canvas.000webhostapp.com/flag.jpg), and [with this kind of movement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUsdKd02htI).

I know there exist some solutions with HTML canvas, but my client specifically requested this be done with CSS3 (and as little javascript as possible). For the waving effect, the only solution I found was to create several `div` elements and have each with an animation delay on the `translateY` to create the flag effect all together ([JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/anaegm/aah90k33/5/)) and do the exact same thing for the text.

I can also make the text overlap the flag by making the text have an absolute position, but my problem is I'm not sure how I can coordinate the wave movement of the text with the flag's so it can be exactly the same. Or, alternatively, if there's another way to do this animation (not sure yet how I'm going to work around the triangles at the edges)? I know [an image can be used to animate over it](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/GEnUU/); what would be more efficient in this case?

Comment: This could be done using CSS3 keyframe animation and toggling background radius

Comment: @X-RaySpecs did you mean border-radius? And wouldn't that just affect the flag? What about the text?

Comment: Is using SVG an option? Or does it really have to be HTML+CSS?

Comment: SVG is an option, but I discovered yesterday that animations in the actual SVG file are possible. When I get it up and running I'll update this question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can do the animation in CSS3 using Keyframes.

You have to have the transparent image which will have the set of frames(all frames in single image) and animate using keyframes.

Here is one Example like that - `https://codepen.io/Guilh/pen/yldGp`

```
HTML
<div class="monster"></div>


CSS
body {
  background: #24aecd;
}

.monster {
  width: 190px;
  height: 240px;
  margin: 2% auto;
  background: url('https://treehouse-code-samples.s3.amazonaws.com/CSS-DD/codepen/blog/monster.png') left center;
  animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
}

@keyframes play {
    100% { background-position: -1900px; }
}
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: Try putting the important part of the answer on Stackoverflow instead of putting it on another site behind a URL.