# CSS3 Waving animation has white lines when zooming in

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to CSS3 animations, and I [was recently tasked with a freelance project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503328/css3-flag-wave-movement-with-text-inside) where I need to animate [this image](http://anaegm.com/flag/demo.svg) as a waving flag. After looking around at examples posted on codepen and JSFiddle, it seemed to me that the best solution was to slice the image, I believe that's what you call it, into several 1px wide elements and animate each of them with a slightly off transition effect to create the waving flag event.

HTML:

```
  <div class="flag"></div>
```

CSS:

```
  .flag {
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: auto;
  }

.flag-element {
  -webkit-animation: oscill 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: oscill 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -ms-animation: oscill 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: oscill 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  background: url('demo.svg');
  max-width: 100%;
  background-size: 200px 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

@-webkit-keyframes oscill {
    100% {
   transform: translateY(3px);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes oscill {
  100% {
  transform: translateY(3px) rotate(0.01deg);
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes oscill {
  100% {
  transform: translateY(3px);
  }
}
@keyframes oscill {
  100% {
  transform: translateY(3px) rotate(0.01deg);
  }
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
var h = $('.flag').width();
for (var i = 0; i < h; i++) {
  var flagElement = $("<div class='flag-element'>");
  flagElement.css('background-position', -i + "px 0");
  flagElement.css('-webkit-animation-delay', i * 10 + 'ms');
  flagElement.css('-moz-animation-delay', i * 10 + 'ms');
  flagElement.css('-ms-animation-delay', i * 10 + 'ms');
  flagElement.css('animation-delay', i * 10 + 'ms');
  $('.flag').append(flagElement);
}
});
```

[Live version](http://anaegm.com/flag/demo.html).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anaegm/hmce3gtk/1/).

The code works great in Chrome, IE, Safari and Firefox, smooth animation and everything. However, be it on mobile or some browsers (like Firefox), when you start zooming in white lines appear over the image ([screencap](http://anaegm.com/flag/screencap.jpg)), and it seems like any kind of transform effect is what's causing this problem. Notably this doesn't happen in all browsers, Chrome renders more smoothly than IE and Firefox, for instance, but is there any way I can make those white lines stop appearing when the user zooms in?

If this is just not solvable, I'm open to alternative solutions to animate this svg like a flag as well. Thanks.

Comment: Try using negative margins on the elements.

Comment: @tricksfortheweb Adding a negative element on the left and right only displaces the whole flag, with white lines still showing up.

Comment: Add the negative margin to each element of the flag, not the flag itself. (Each `.flag-element`, not `.flag`)

Comment: @tricksfortheweb That's what I meant before, excuse me, adding a left and/or right negative margin or just margins on all sides under the `flag-element` class simply displaced the flag as a whole, would you mind demonstrating in the JSFiddle?

Comment: is it only on android?

Comment: why do some of the `@keyframes` (the `-moz-` prefix one) have a rotate in the transform and some don't? It might be what's causing the issue.

Comment: @tricksfortheweb As mentioned in the question this is happening on Firefox and IE as well, not just android. I added a rotation to some of the keyframes to enable anti aliasing on Firefox (a hack, I know, but if I don't add it it looks terrible). And no, removing those don't solve the issue.

Comment: If you're into hacks, why don't you try using a box-shadow on the elements to spread the gray color around?

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb That would create shadows on the triangle edges, making it look like a rectangle, and it doesn't seem to do the trick either.

Comment: I don't know, then. If someone doesn't answer it in a while I can put a bounty on it.

Comment: @tricksfortheweb thank you so much! I'm really at the end of my rope here.

Comment: Am i missing something? is there no working example in the fiddle (only code and the example online)?

Comment: Looks like a lot of css animations have this problem when zooming. I think you should go with SVG. Then you're shure everything looks perfect at anytime and it's i think better for performance. Something like this: https://codepen.io/elaraby/pen/epWjPP

Comment: @OlivierKrull Thanks, I'll look into this as an alternative. Will update this question if I can make it work.

Comment: Hi Ana, i wonder if and how you solved your issue?